# Unsupport MediaType when create entity with string value for post to restapi

Tags: java

I failed to post a string entity request to `restApi` with `http` `415 error`. The code detail is :

```
String testDownloadUrl = s3://file-upload-service/eb168cb4-2b8d-4ecd-9c45-6baa728b51f

Response response = ClientBuilder.newClient().register(MultiPartFeature.class)
                                     .target(url)
                                     .request()
                                     .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + this.authToken)
                                  .post(Entity.text(testDownloadUrl));
```

Anybody knows how to fix it?